Nodejs (lambda) - Kinesis GetMedia Store S3 and watch
Ive been struggling with a use case. I have video being stored at a high bit rate (about 1mbps) to kinesis video and don’t want to increase the retention period beyond 2 weeks due to costs.
Therefore i want to move 40 minutes of video from kinesis video to s3 for more permanent storage. API GetClip has a 100 mb limit so i was reviewing GetMedia instead. The response TYPE from getMedia is foreign to me. How can i store the response from getMedia (concert TYPE if necessary) and store it to s3, then download it through a custom ApI to view it in browser.
Looking for a simple code sample. Ive seen some comments on ffpmeg. Any code samples available?
Thank you
P.s. I have tried returning the result from GetMedia to postman. The return from GetMedia is a video/webm tyoe file. Which i don’t know how to work with.
